# How to use var inside getRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to use a var (in A1 notation) inside a getRange?

```
function reservar() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var form = ss.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
var ss_calendario = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1r0jLPIfOAmOD7Lim9qmscQsrx5GAworz6ug1O-XAHDg');
var calendario = ss_calendario.getSheetByName("Disponibilidad");

var rango = form.getRange(1,1,form.getLastRow(),16);
var data = rango.getValues()

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {  
  var columna = data[i];
  var disponible = columna[9];
  var celda = columna[14];

  if(disponible == "Disponible"){
    calendario.getRange(celda).setValue(true);
  }
 }
}
```

In the last line of code im trying to set to true the calendars day of the A1 notation value of the var `celda` but i keep getting the no interval found message.

> [18-05-27 14:06:54:406 ART] Sheet.getRange(["Celda"]) [0,108 segundos]
>   [18-05-27 14:06:54:455 ART] Ejecución fallida: No se ha encontrado el intervalo. (línea 16, archivo "Código") [0,478 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]

I assume it's being passed `["Celda"]`, isn't that the type of value im looking for? i.e "B71"

Comment: Check the Execution transcript. It will show you what is the value being passed to getRange.

Comment: [...]
[18-05-27 14:06:54:406 ART] Sheet.getRange(["Celda"]) [0,108 segundos]


[18-05-27 14:06:54:455 ART] Ejecución fallida: No se ha encontrado el intervalo. (línea 16, archivo "Código") [0,478 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]

I assume its being passed ["Celda"], isnt that the type of value im looking for? i.e "B71"

Comment: `celda` is not a range, it's a value. You'll need to call the range by using `i+1` (assuming you start on row 1) for the row and col 15 (or `form.getLastColumn()`)

Comment: [18-05-27 15:13:12:509 ART] Logger.log(["Celda", []]) [0 segundos]

toString(); still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the value that you are getting is the column header on your sheet, specially because your loop starts on 0.

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
```